# Ionic/Angular CSS Problems with image

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic5

I’m setting a background image in a css file, i have been doing for the last 13 years but for some reason ionic/angular is screwing something up.
In my css file, I have this:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url('../../../assets/headers/address.png');
}
```

But it doesn’t render the image and when I inspect element it writes:

> background-image: url(address.png)

Comment: you need to add the directory structure as well, so that others can see how this css file is in relation with assets folder.

Comment: Hey @Prince scr > assets > headers > 'images here' as for the rest of the structure: src > app > subscription > uaddress > 'ts, scss, html here'.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by removing all the `../` and leaving `/assets/`

Answer (score -1):

you can try this css,

```
.image{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(D:\qwe\ert\apn\dashboard\src\assets\icon\favicons\android-chrome-384x384.png) no-repeat center top;//address image
}
```

Comment: Once the app compiles it won't work because the absolute path doesn't exist on the compiler. It needs to come from localhost or something like that.